# is basic/digest auth sufficient in terms of security, for using an API from a Google Chrome Extension?

Tags: authentication, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is basic/digest auth sufficient for a google chrome extension to authenticate into a web based API? Can someone hack into it?  I thought that I dont need OAuth because the API is not a 3rd party API but part of my service (for which I plan to create an API and the Google Chrome extension which will use the API...)